# Transfer cell value to another worksheet without copy and paste?

Tags: vba, excel

My goal is to transfer cell value from workbook2 to workbook1. This is the situation setup. I would like to transfer cell value from cell O4 to the end of the column (which contains at least 138 lines) in workbook2 to cell D147 to Dxxx in workbook1.

This is what my VBA code looks like. My problem is VBA doesn't understand what I am trying to tell the program to do up until line 6.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\zyu\Documents\Processed Data\Allagash\16 cells\Copy of TXM10421_24M_capacity_102113.xls")

wb1.Sheets("sheet1").Range("D147", Range("D147").End(xlToLeft)).value = wb2.Sheet("16").Range("O4").value

End Sub
```

Comment: you want the value of O4 in "D147:D" Last Column?

Comment: Yes, your description suggests you are trying to copy a column of data, but your code uses `xlToLeft`? You should clarify this first.

Comment: @siddharth rout I want the value of O4 in D147, O5 in D148, O6 in D149 and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @siddharth rout I want the value of O4 in D147, O5 in D148, O6 in D149 and so on

Is this what you are trying (UNTESTED)?

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyrow2()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow  As Long

    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("sheet1")

    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\zyu\Documents\Processed Data\16 cells\Copy of TXM10421_24M_capacity_102113.xls")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("16")

    With ws1
        lastRow = ws2.Range("O" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("D147").Resize(lastRow, 1).Value = ws2.Range("O4:O" & lastRow).Value
    End With
End Sub
```